# How to convert a GeoJSON to be within -90 and 90

Tags: qgis, geojson, scale

I use QGIS to draw a floorplan diagram that contain many MultiPolygons. By default it is using WGS 84, EPSG:4326. After finish I export it to GeoJSON. By checking the file in mapshaper.org, the shapes look good. However when I upload the same file to geojson.io it returned error "Invalid JSON file: Error: Invalid LngLat latitude value: must be between -90 and 90"

Since I am drawing a floorplan of an office not a country map, I believe I should convert it to smaller scale. What should I do to correct my GeoJSON or the drawing?

Comment: GeoJSON always use WGS84 long/lat coordinates. You should not use it as a transport format for floorplans as you will always run into precision problems. Pick a better projection (i.e. one in metres) and a better format (almost anything)